# How do I set the UNC permissions on a SQL Server 2008 Filestream UNC?

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

I have a SQL Server 2008 instance. I have configured [filestream access properly](http://sqlsrvengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FileStreamEnable&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=sqlsrvengine), and use it from one column on one table in one of my databases. However, I cannot access the UNC share for the filestream data. I have tried browsing to it as well as trying to open specific files and I get errors both ways.

I am running SQL Server 2008 enterprise on a Windows 7 workstation running on the domain. I've tried running the sql server service as a local user, then as network admin. The user I am logged in as is a local admin and a sysadmin in SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how filestream works - you don't browse the share and open files directly. You need to go through SQL Server to obtain a logical file path and transaction context and then use these two when opening the file (either using Win32 [OpenSqlFilestream API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933972.aspx) or .Net [SqlFileStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx)). Here's a tutorial on how to access filestream data from windows applications: [Managing FILESTREAM Data by Using Win32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645940.aspx) .

Comment: Looks like you are right.